# Show that $\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^\infty \cos(jx) = 0$ in the Cesàro sense

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

So, we have $s_n = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^n \cos(jx)$ and we wish to show that $s_n = 0$ in the Cesàro sense. My understanding of the Cesàro method is to take $\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N s_n}{N}$ which yields $\frac{1}{2N} + \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \cos(nx)}{N} \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Is this correct?

Comment: Do you mean $s_n=\frac{1}{2}+\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(jx)$, and what is $x$?

Comment: Also you should be finding the limit of the averages (the first thing you wrote), not $\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(jx)}{n}$.

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x \not \equiv 0$ mod $2\pi$

Comment: Yes I meant $\sum_{j=1}^{n}$. I changed it. I'm not sure that I completely understand why the $\frac{1}{2}$ isn't multiplied by the $\frac{1}{N}$. My guess is that it's because $\frac{1}{2}$ doesn't involve $n$ terms.

Comment: Because you are finding the limit of $s_1,\frac{1}{2}(s_1+s_2),\frac{1}{3}(s_1+s_2+s_3),\ldots$, so $\frac{\sum_{k=1}^ns_k}{n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^k\cos(jx)$.

Comment: $cos(jx)= \Re{e}(exp(jx})$ so the series $\sum_{j=1}^n cos(jx)$ is the real part of the geometric series $\sum_{j=1}^n exp(j i x)$ which is calculated as $\frac {e^{i ( n+1 ) x}}{e^{ix}-1}-\frac 
{e^{ix}}{e^{ix}-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show that $\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\cos(jx)$ is Cesaro summable to $0$ you must show that the average value of partial sums converges to $0$, that is

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^nS_k = 0,$$

where

$$S_k = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{j=1}^{k}\cos(jx)= \frac{\sin[(k + 1/2)x]}{2 \sin(x/2)} .$$

Hence,

$$\frac1{n} \sum_{k=1}^nS_k = \frac1{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\sin[(k + 1/2)x]}{2 \sin(x/2)}.$$

It can be shown that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \sin[(k + 1/2)x] =  \frac{\sin(nx/2)\sin[(n+2)x/2]}{\sin(x/2)}.$$

Hence,

$$\begin{align} \frac1{n} \sum_{k=1}^nS_k &= \frac1{2n}\frac{\sin(nx/2)\sin[(n+2)x/2]}{\sin^2(x/2)}\end{align},$$

and the RHS converges to $0$ as $ n \to \infty$ for $x$ not equal to a multiple of $2\pi$.

Comment: Why does $\frac{1}{n}$ not apply to the $\frac{1}{2}$ in line 3?

Comment: @JSikes: Because $\frac1{n} \sum_{k=1}^n 1/2 = 1/2$. I will simplify above to avoid this.